# Constraint on Composite Type

Tags: postgresql, constraint, postgresql-9.2

How can I create a constraint on a sub-field of composite type?

**Pseudocode**

```
create type axis(
    major_axis float,
    minor_axis float,
    angle float constraint angle_constraint check(angle between -90 and 90)
);

create table sample(
    axis1 axis,
    axis2 axis
);
```

Is this possible in PostgreSQL 9.2? It seems to be not possible in 9.1 as mentioned [here](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/check-constraints-on-composite-type-td5134991.html).

Comment: What are you storing in angle? the angle to what?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Well, it could be anything. Some example might be angle of normalized rotation (from 0 to 360) or pitch/roll/yaw angle (-180 to +180).

Comment: but I wouldn't store pitch/roll/yaw like that. I would store the major/minor as a PostGIS point on a table that had columns dedicated to x/y/z, time, and pitch/roll/yaw.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Well, the point is that, the three columns are related, and IMHO that's the point of grouping distinct data into "classes" or user defined data structure.

Comment: They're not really related -- (X/Y are, because neither one of them stands by itself). Pitch/yaw/roll are not related: they all stand individually. So I (and most others) would store this in a table that was `CREATE TABLE ( geog geography(pointz 4326), pitch float, yaw float, roll float )`. With this method of storage you could use a PostGIS aggregate to get a linesegment that represented the flight path (and the like)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use CREATE DOMAIN with a CHECK constraint. This works in PostgreSQL 9.1. It's [documented to work in at least 8.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/rowtypes.html)+. "A partial workaround is to use domain types as members of composite types."

```
create domain angle as float check (value between -90 and 90);

create type axis as (
    major_axis float,
    minor_axis float,
    angle angle
);

create table sample(
    axis1 axis,
    axis2 axis
);
```

This INSERT statement should succeed.

```
insert into sample values
(row(0, 0, 35), row(0, 0, 35));
```

But this one should fail.

```
insert into sample values
(row(0, 0, 93), row(0, 0, 35));
ERROR: value for domain angle violates check constraint "angle_check"
SQL state: 23514
```

Comment: @Vineet: A [`DOMAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createdomain.html) would only be ruled out if you'd want to check on a combination of columns in the composite type. But that does not seem to be the case, so this should be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I would store them separately and **not** as a composite type. There is a geospatial component here. I would store that as a PostGIS Geography type which is in fact composite: the x getter is [`ST_X`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html), and y getter is [`ST_Y`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html)

```
CREATE TABLE plane_path (
  id    int  PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  geog  geography(pointz, 4326),
  ts    timestamp with time zone,
  pitch float,
  yaw   float,
  roll  float
);
```

Or if you want, you could represent your angle as a DOMAIN and put it on the table too.

```
CREATE DOMAIN angle AS float CHECK (value between -90 and 90);

CREATE TABLE plane_path (
  id    int  PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  geog  geography(pointz, 4326),
  ts    timestamp with time zone,
  pitch angle,
  yaw   angle,
  roll  angle
);
```

With this schema and PostGIS, you could easily aggregate the points into a linepath representing the trajectory with [`ST_MakeLine`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html)

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [9.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/rowtypes.html) and [9.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/rowtypes.html) don't differ from [9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/rowtypes.html) with regard to CHECK contraints for composite types. It's safe to assume that this is still not possible.